# Need to Fix Scrape PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, scraper

We've a PHP script that scrapes search engine results pages and outputs clients website positions into a bespoke report suite for their domains.

Google changed something in the first week of February which prevented our script from detecting the domain on the page and I haven't currently got the original developer in the office nor can any of our other staff resolve this.

I pretty sure I know where the issue lies in the script, it's just, as I'm not a developer, I'm unsure what each line is actually doing. Our script uses the relevant classes from the search results to determine where what we're looking for is actually situated.

The script itself still runs and outputs the HTML fine. It's purely just the part of the script that says look for 'domain' on page that isn't being detected.

I appreciate that you're probably going to need a lot more information from me in order to advise what the issue is and I am happy to provide the file/coding as necessary. I would be prepared to pay for a fix on this too if necessary.

Below is where I feel the issue is occurring:-

```
// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos4 === false) {
    $mystring5 = $val[0];
    $findme5 = $prevlink;
    $pos5 = @strpos($mystring5, $findme5);
    // Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
    // because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
    if ($pos5 === false) {
        $serp = $serp + 1;
        echo '<b>'.$serp.'.</b> '.$val[0].'<br /><br />';
        $link = get_string_between($val[1], 'href="', '" onmousedown');
        $link = str_replace('https://','',$link);
        $link = str_replace('http://','',$link);
        $link = str_replace('www.','',$link);
        $link;
        $prevlink = $link;
        $prevlink = str_replace(strstr($prevlink, '/'), "", $prevlink);
        $sitelen = strlen($row_site_check['website_name']);
        $sitefrom_link = substr($link, 0, $sitelen);
        if ($sitefrom_link == $row_site_check['website_name']) {
            $site_found = 1;
            $rank_postion = $serp;
            $site_link = $link;
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","dbpass");
            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to suppress errors and warnings for strpos, the docs don't mention it generates any.

Comment: Also, `var_dump` is your friend and `get_string_between` is not defined here, make sure it reaches up to that point with expected values using `var_dump`.

Comment: I'd not suppress errors at all.  You'll only make your own life harder in the long run.

Comment: Could it be that Google have changed their HTML layout?  If you're doing screen-scraping, then you're probably using regular expressions over their HTML to find domains.  If they've changed their HTML, then it's more than likely that your regular expressions won't match anymore - they'll need to be updated for the new layout.

Comment: I only supressed strpos error as it was being outputted on the page when I ran scan (I believe because it wasn't defined) but I'm pretty certain this is unrelated to the issue though.

Comment: All data we check for is in MySQL database too by the way, it goes through the motions correctly but purely doesn't detect the domain on the page (even though it is there). I'm guessing msgmash.com is probably correct in saying that our regular expressions need updating but I don't know what that means really :( The script itself is much bigger if it will be of any use seeing the full code (237 lines)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Google rank scraper](http://google-rank-checker.squabbel.com)  (php, opensource)

I am using software based on it daily since it was released and there was no change of Googles layout in February that broke anything as far as I can tell.

I'm not sure if you'll like the answer but the reason is likely that the Rank Scraper I pasted uses DOM to parse the HTML of google while you seem to rely on regular expressions and string operations.
I've personally tried to make a scraper based on such methods in the past and found that it requires a lot of maintenance work to keep it running. Sometimes real ugly workarounds.
When using DOM small changes usually don't even damage anything and otherwise adapting the code might be easier.
In the past few years the DOM code of that parser was working without major interruption, only two times a small change had to be made. And Google did change a lot on their site in that time, it just didn't cause ill effects.

The DOM functions of the above linked checker can be found in the functions.php file

```
function process_raw($htmdata,$page)
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. We actually fixed our script ourselves in the end - it was a change in the URL parameters for Google search that caused ours to break. I'm aware of the one you've linked to above actually - based on your input, it sounds like we would be better suited to utilise this one so will see if one of our developers can look into getting it set up on our server. Thanks :)